# Mysql query insert from another table

Tags: mysql, insert

When using the query below I'm inserting product_id and I also want to set field category_id = 4 for all inserted product_ids. Here's my code to insert products.

```
INSERT INTO lc_products_to_categories
( product_id)
SELECT product_id
FROM lc_products_info
where name like '%awesome product%'
```

How to update category_id with single query?

Comment: just select the constant like this  NSERT INTO lc_products_to_categories
( product_id,category_id) product_id, 4 FROM lc_products_info
where name like '%awesome product%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO lc_products_to_categories
( product_id, category_id)
SELECT product_id, 4
FROM lc_products_info
where name like '%awesome product%'
```